# Adding a Div if the data length changes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to "update" a list of data collected from a database. As it stands my code prints out the list of values into a div. I want it only to append a new Coordinate set + value if one is found after it checks, not keep printing the same set over again.

I tried to clear the body but I want it to update the div as it goes along not clear it completely.I used

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

to clear it.

you can see here how it repeats the same values, I want the Marker Value to update the existing div entry.

[image]

```
Parse.initialize("API", "API");



var mValue = Parse.Object.extend("mValue");
var queryLngLat = new Parse.Query(mValue);
var classObject = new mValue();
var existingMarkers= [];
var databaseMarkers= [];
var counter = 0;
var div ;
var resultsLength;


setInterval(function update() {

queryLngLat.notEqualTo("longAndLat", null);
queryLngLat.find({
  success: function(results) {

      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");

     for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++ ) {
    databaseMarkers = (results[j].attributes.longAndLat);
resultsLength = results.length;

     var  markerValueRead = results[j].attributes.Val;

     CoordsPush = databaseMarkers.substring(1, databaseMarkers.length - 1);

     div =  document.createElement("div");
      div.style.width = "400px;";
    div.style.background = "white";
    div.style.color = "black";
    div.innerHTML = "Database LatLng: " + CoordsPush + " Marker Value: " + markerValueRead;                                     document.body.appendChild(div);

    //console.log("(" + markers[d].getPosition().d + ", " + markers[d].getPosition().e +")");

    console.log("Database LatLng: " + databaseMarkers + " Marker Value: " + markerValueRead);

        }

    }

    });


}, 10000);

});
```

Comment: Do you want to update the div value instead of creating new divs? Can you try to clarify a little more what you want?

Comment: What I want to do is create a new div or list item (doesn't matter which) for each Coordinate set and value. As It is in my screenshot. then if the value changes on the database I want it to update if its already been created and if it hasn't been created before then add it to the bottom of the list. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Well then you will obviously have to check for which values there already _is_ an existing element displaying them.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an **id** to each div created that is a unique identifier of the Coordinate displayed by this div.

Something like

```
div =  document.createElement("div");
div.id = CoordsPush         // <---- ADD THIS LINE
div.style.width = "400px;";
div.style.background = "white";
div.style.color = "black";
div.innerHTML = "Database LatLng: " + CoordsPush + " Marker Value: " + markerValueRead;                                     document.body.appendChild(div);
```

then add code to check if a div with that id already exists before creating a new one. And update the existing div with the new value you just got from the backend.

EDIT: Maybe you need to transform the coordinates string value to make it a valid id

Comment: I have added a counter which adds "div" + counter so div1 div2 div3 etc. But due to my code it just clears the existing ones and re-adds them rather than leaving them and updating the Val

Comment: You need to correlate the div identifier with the data inside it, otherwise you will not be able to match it later with new data coming from the backend. I suggested using the CoordsPush because that is all the info I have. If you can add yourself some kind of identifier for the rows in the backend, even better.

Comment: @Dan you have to add an if clause to check if the div is already there, otherwise of course it will only create new ones.

Comment: I've set each div id created to whatever the LatLng is of that value, which should make it easy for me to retrieve the data inside that div if I know which latLng it is. Although it is not entirely the answer I wanted I think it will be enough for my project! I've +1'd your answer.

Comment: @Dan: If you give me more details on what is missing, I can improve the answer :)